# Minimax theorem in a changed game

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have a question regarding the minimax theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem

Does anyone know whether the theorem holds also for **negative** x and y? i.e. $x_i <0, y_j <0$ possible.

If i compute the optimal x and y with the "linprog" function in matlab and the conditions: $$\sum_i x_i=1 , \quad x_i \in \mathbb{R}, \quad x_i>-10$$ (same for y), i get two different values: X gets at least v1 and Y pays at most v2, with v1$>$v2. But i expect them to be equal if the theorem holds..

Comment: Your feasible region is not closed. Suppose you made it closed, does it meet the requirements of the theorem on Wikipedia? Could you share the numerical example that you checked with v1>v2?

Comment: What do you mean with a "negative mixed strategy" in this context ?

Comment: Thanks @LinAlg - I think, if \sum_i x_i=1 and there is a lower bound for x_i (-10), than the region is closed.. I added the code

Comment: Thanks @Peter - the components of the mixed startegies x_i and y_j can be negative

Comment: Aren't $x_i$ and $y_j$ probabilities ? If yes, how can they be negative ?

Comment: your linprog input is flawed, see https://vanderbei.princeton.edu/542/lectures/lec8.pdf for how you find optimal strategies

Comment: Thanks @LinAlg . Can you specify why the input is flawed or do you assume it because of the two different results v1,v2? for non-negative x_i, y_j the program computes the correct strategies. I checked that with different payoff matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) indicates in one of the comments, if $\ x_i\ $ or $\ y_j\ $ can be negative, it makes no sense to regard $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ as *mixed* strategies, or $\ x^TCy\ $ as an "average" payoff to player X.  However, you can perfectly well regard $\ x^TCy\ $ as the payoff to X in a zero-sum game where $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ are regarded as *pure* strategies.  It is then true that the game you give as an example does have optimal *pure* strategies $\ x^*=\left(1,-1,1\right)^T\ $ and $\ y^*=\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{5}\right)^T\ $. Since
$$
{x^*}^T\pmatrix{2&-1&1\\
1&0&-1\\-1&1&-2}=\left(0, 0, 0\right)\ ,
$$
and
$$
\pmatrix{2&-1&1\\
1&0&-1\\-1&1&-2}y^*=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}\ ,
$$
then
$$
{x^*}^T\pmatrix{2&-1&1\\
1&0&-1\\-1&1&-2}y=0
$$
for *all* pure strategies $\ y\ $ of Y, and
$$
x^T\pmatrix{2&-1&1\\
1&0&-1\\-1&1&-2}y^*=0
$$
for *all* pure strategies $\ x\ $ of X.  Thus $\ x^*\ $ guarantees X a payoff of exactly $\ 0\ $, and $\ y^*\ $ guarantees that Y suffers a loss of exactly $\ 0\ $.

More generally, if $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are any non-empty compact convex subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}^m\ $ and $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ respectively, $\ C\ $ an $\ m\times n\ $ matrix with real entries, and $\ f(x,y)=x^TCy\ $ for $\ x\in X $ and $\ y\in Y\ $, it follows from a minimax theorem of [Ky Fan](https://en.org/wiki/Ky_Fan) (in particular, from Theorem $1$(ii) of [this paper](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-a5df9748f7b26541fff82d19505cef5a/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-a5df9748f7b26541fff82d19505cef5a.pdf))  that $\ f\ $ has a saddle point, $\ (x^*, y^*) $ in $\ X\times Y\ $—that is,
$$
f(x,y^*)\le f(x*,y)\ \text{ for all }\ (x,y)\in X\times Y\ .
$$
If $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are convex compact polyhedra, the optimal strategies can be found with a pair of dual linear programs, by linearly transforming $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ into polyhedral subsets of probability simplices in $\ \mathbb{R}^{m+1}\ $ and $\ \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ $ respectively.

In the example given by the OP, however, the polyhedra have the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^mx_i=s,\ \ a_i\le x_i \ \text{ for all }\ i\\
\sum_{i=j}^ny_j=t,\ \ b_j\le y_j \ \text{ for all }\ j\ ,
$$
where $\ s, t, a_i, b_j\ $ could be *any* constants, with $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^m a_i<s\ $ and $\ \sum_\limits{j=1}^n b_j<t\ $. It's possible to transform polyhedra of this form into probability simplices by changing variables to $\ \xi_i=\frac{x_i-a_i}{s-\sum_\limits{i=1}^ma_i}\ $ and $\ \eta_j= \frac{y_j-b_j}{t-\sum_\limits{j=1}^nb_j}\ $, which then satisfy the constraints
$$
\sum_{i=1}^mx_i= \sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j=1,\ \xi_i,\eta_j\ge0\ .
$$
The payoff to player X in terms of these new variables is
\begin{align}
\left(\sigma\xi+a\right)^TC\left(\tau\eta+b\right)=\xi^T\overline{C}\eta
\end{align}
where $\ \sigma=s-\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\ $, $\ \tau=t-\sum_{j=1}^nb_j\ $, $\ \overline{C}=$$ \sigma\tau C+\sigma Cb\mathbb{1}_n^T+\tau \mathbb{1}_ma^TC+ \mathbb{1}_m a^TCb \mathbb{1}_n^T\ $, and $\ \mathbb{1}_r\ $ is an $\ r\times1\ $ column vector whose entries are all $1$.  Thus the original game is equivalent to a zero-sum game with payoff matrix $\ \overline{C}\ $, and strategies $\ \xi\ $ and $\ \eta\ $ lying in the probability simplices of $\ \mathbb{R}^m\ $ and $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ respectively, which can be solved in the same way as a standard zero-sum matrix game with payoff matrix $\ \overline{C}\ $.

Since the original matrix $\ C\ $ given by the OP is singular, it is easy to find column vectors $\ x\ $ and $\ y $ such that $\ x^TC=0_{1\times3}\ $ and $\ Cy=0_{3\times1}\ $, and to scale them so that they satisfy the constraints. Transforming the problem in the manner described above is therefore not really necessary.  Nevertheless, to illustrate the procedure, I use it below to derive the solution given above.

For the example given by the OP,
\begin{align}
a=b&=\pmatrix{-10\\-10\\-10}\\
s=t&=1\\
\sigma=\tau&=31,\ \text{and}\\
\overline{C}=&\pmatrix{682&-1581&961\\341&0&-341\\-961&1581&-682}\ .
\end{align}
The optimal mixed strategies for the  zero-sum matrix game with matrix $\ \overline{C}\ $ are
\begin{align}
\xi^*&=\pmatrix{\frac{11}{31}, \frac{9}{31},\frac{11}{31}}^T\ \text{and}\\
\eta^*&=\pmatrix{\frac{51}{155},\frac{53}{155}, \frac{51}{155}}^T\ ,
\end{align}
which give
\begin{align}
x^*&=\sigma\xi^*+a\\
  &= \left(1,-1,1\right)^T\ \text{and}\\
y^*&=\tau\eta^*+b\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{5}\right)^T
\end{align}
as the optimal pure strategies for the original problem.

Comment: Apologies for the typo in my original answer, and consequent solution of the wrong problem. I have now corrected this. I believe you are mistaken about the $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ derived from the optimal $\ \xi\ $ and $\ \eta\ $ not being optimal for the original problem. The $\ x^*\ $ and $\ y^*\ $ I give in my updated answer, which are clearly optimal for your original problem *were*, in fact, so derived.

Comment: The mappings $\ x\rightarrow\xi\ $ and $\ y\rightarrow\eta\ $ are bijections from the original spaces of strategies to probability simplices, and $\ xCy^T=\xi(x)^T\overline{C}\eta(y)\ $ for all $\ x,y\ $.  Therefore, if $\ \xi^*, \eta^*\ $ are optimal for the game with matrix $\ \overline{C}\ $, and $\ \xi\left(x^*\right)=$$\xi^*, $$\eta\left(y^*\right)=$$\eta^*\ $, then
\begin{align}
xC{y^*}^T&=\xi(x)^T\overline{C}\eta^*\\
&\le{\xi^*}^T\overline{C}\eta(y)\\
&=x^*Cy^T
\end{align}
for all $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $.

Comment: Oh no, it's certainly possible.  Just take the linear programs for solving the transformed game and express them in terms of the original variables.  The linear program for finding $\ x^*\ $ for instance, is
\begin{align}
\text{maximise}&\hspace{1em}v\\
\text{subject to}\ &\cases{0\le&$\frac{(x-a)\overline{C}}{\sigma}-v \mathbb{1}_n$\\
1=&$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n x_i$\\
a\le&$x$
}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, that's it.  To be sure that the usual linear programs will return optimal strategies you need the entries of the vectors you're optimising over to both be non-negative and sum to one.  Otherwise, you can't deduce that $\ v\le {x^*}^TCy\ $ for all $\ y\ $, for instance, merely from the fact that $\ v\le ({x^*}^TC)_j\ $ for every $\ j\ $.

Comment: Yes. Multiplying or dividing any constraint by a positive constant won't change the set of feasible solutions.

Comment: To prove that the implication doesn't hold, all you need is a single counterexample. Suppose that $\ v= 0,$$\ \left(x^{*T}C\right)_1=0\ $, and $ \left(x^{*T}C\right)_2=1\ $.  Then for $\ y_1=2,$$y_2=-1,\ $ and $\ y_j=0\ $ for all other $\ j\ $, we have $\ x^{*T}Cy=-1<v\ $.